# File upload in PHP not working?

Tags: php

My file upload system just isn't working properly, it doesn't return true when I call `move_uploaded_file()`. Here is my code, not sure if i'm just blind:

HTML:

```
<form action="updatecheat.php" method="POST">
                            <label for="version">Version:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="version" name="version" placeholder="New Version Number" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="referrer" id="referrer" value="coven-updates.php" />
                            <div class="custom-file-upload">
<label for="covenupdate">Upload "Coven.exe"</label>
<input type="file" id="covenupdate" name="covenupdate" />
</div>

<br /><br />

<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success waves-effect waves-light m-r-10">Update</button>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$errors= array();
          $file_name = $_FILES['covenupdate']['name'];
          $file_size =$_FILES['covenupdate']['size'];
          $file_tmp =$_FILES['covenupdate']['tmp_name'];
          $file_type=$_FILES['covenupdate']['type'];



if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../Coven/Utilites/Update/".$file_name)){
                $fn = "../Coven/Utilities/Version.txt"; 
            $file = fopen($fn, "w+"); 
            $size = filesize($fn); 

            fwrite($file, $_POST['version']); 

            $text = fread($file, $size); 
            fclose($file);

            header("Location: urlhere");

             } else {
                header("Location: urlhere");
             }
```

I have no clue why it isn't uploading properly. Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Have checked whether file posted.you need to add one more parameters in your form

Comment: Encrept multipart/formdata

Comment: Ram is correct - your form is missing the right encoding: multipart/form-data

Comment: you need to include enctype for a file ulpload to work .i.e enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your form tag you are missing one attribute enctype='multipart/form-data' which is must while you are working with upload file.

So, just change your form tag to this:

```
<form action="updatecheat.php" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to include enctype for a file ulpload to work .i.e enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

Try with add attribute `enctype='multipart/form-data'`  and

File will be stored in temporary location, use `tmp_name` instead of name

```
if(move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"../Coven/Utilites/Update/".$file_name)){
```